# python get list of partial strings from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, find, tuples

I have a list of tuples, its dates and times, from;to

```
print datetime
```

gives

```
[(u'2017-09-10-14-00-35;2017-09-10-14-15-46',), (u'2017-09-10-13-45-23;2017-09-10-14-00-35',), (u'2017-09-10-13-30-05;2017-09-10-13-45-23',)]
```

I want to make a new list, but only of the 'to' times:

```
['2017-09-10-14-15-46', '2017-09-10-14-00-35', '2017-09-10-13-45-23']
```

I cant seem to put all the elements together, so far I have

```
for a in datetime:
    for b in a:
        enddates = [b[b.find(";")+1:] for b in a]
print enddates
```

gives the last result only, not the list

```
[u'2017-09-10-13-45-23']
```

Have not given up easily, but down a rabbit hole on this

Comment: Just partition the single element in the tuple? `end_dates = [el[0].partition(';')[2] for el in datetime]` ?

Comment: @JonClements same solution: gives me the creeps... (I used `rpartition` for some reason...)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm going to have to keep looking over my shoulder am I? :p

Comment: Not to worry :). I think you're using `partition` for the same reason as me: if `;` is not in the string, it doesn't crash like it would with `str.splt()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre also it's special cased for a single split (much faster than str.split with a maxsplit of 1 - if you're only splitting once - it means you can't forget to supply a maxsplit argument to `str.split`.

Comment: @JonClements. Interesting. So I'll keep on using it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need any loop, just pick the first & unique item from each tuple, and perform `str.partition` on it (take 2nd element: the rightmost one), in a list comprehension like you tried

```
a = [(u'2017-09-10-14-00-35;2017-09-10-14-15-46',), (u'2017-09-10-13-45-23;2017-09-10-14-00-35',), (u'2017-09-10-13-30-05;2017-09-10-13-45-23',)]

enddates = [b[0].partition(";")[2] for b in a]

print(enddates)
```

result:

```
['2017-09-10-14-15-46', '2017-09-10-14-00-35', '2017-09-10-13-45-23']
```

Answer (score 0):

With `str.split()` function:

```
dt = [(u'2017-09-10-14-00-35;2017-09-10-14-15-46',), (u'2017-09-10-13-45-23;2017-09-10-14-00-35',), (u'2017-09-10-13-30-05;2017-09-10-13-45-23',)]
result = [d[0].split(';')[1] for d in dt]
print(result)
```

Or the same with `str.rfind()` function:

```
...
result = [d[0][d[0].rfind(';')+1:] for d in dt]
```

---

The output:

```
['2017-09-10-14-15-46', '2017-09-10-14-00-35', '2017-09-10-13-45-23']
```